# Computed v-model check?

Tags: vue.js

как проверять длина числа которая была введена в input больше 5 тогда выводить что-то в консоль

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
    return {
        test: ''
    }
},
computed() {
    if (test.length >= 5) {
            console.log('more 5')
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Есть два способа это сделать. Это повесить `watch` на свойство или обращаться к другому `computed` свойству.

Пример с `watch`:

```js
data() {
  return {
    text_value: '',
  }
},

watch: {
  text_value(value) {
    if (value.length > 5) {
      console.log('Строка больше пяти символов!');
    }
  }
}
```

Пример с `computed`:

```js
data() {
  text_value: '',
},

computed: {
  text_value_length() {
    if (this.text_value.length > 5) {
      console.log('Строка больше пяти символов!');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: а как придумать если у меня v-model="test.item"
типа как обьект .

Comment: @babakov.roman678 используйте `deep`. https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#watch